# Understanding notation (linear continuous functional on $C[a,b]$)

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

Let $C = C([a,b],\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a space of continuous vectorvalued functions on $[a,b]$. Let $y \in C$, $\Phi \in C^*$ and $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$. What does mean a notation
$$
   A = \int\limits_{a}^{b} f(d\Phi(t))^{T} y(t)
$$
If $\Phi \in C^{1}([a,b],\mathbb{R}^n)$ then
$$
   A = \int\limits_{a}^{b} f(\Phi'(t))^{T}y(t)dt,
$$
but in general case I'm confused.

Another example of use of similar notation is further: 
$$
   \int\limits_{a}^{b} \delta^{*}(d\Phi(t) \mid M(t))
$$
Here $\delta^{*}(\cdot \mid M(t))$ is a support function for the set $M(t)$.

Comment: The "dot product" usually denotes the pairing between a vector space and its dual: if $v$ is a vector and $f$ is a linear functional, then $\langle f,v\rangle:=f(v)$.

Comment: In my particular case $f(x)$ is a given function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and instead of dot product author uses $f(d\Phi(t))^{T}y(t)$ (so it is only a question of notation). I'll correct my question to make it unambiguous.

Comment: Indeed, that is rather confusing. For example, with $n=1$, $f(x)=x^2$, $[a,b]=[-1,1]$ and $\Phi=\delta$ (Dirac's delta), we seem to be asking for $\delta^2$, which is not really well defined. Maybe you could provide a reference to the book or paper you're reading?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give a reference, but I can update my question with a particular example.